# Row Level Security in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi

I created the Report in PowerBi desktop and Published in the PowerBI service. In the workspace  we have 4 users each of them from different region, I need to set the RLS from the user table. The requirement is I should not use the available option "Manage Roles" in PowerBi desktop.

Kindly share your thoughts!!!

Thanks

Comment: There are many guides on this including the official MS one https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/admin/service-admin-rls Please try implementing yourself and post when you have a specific issue

Comment: RLS == "Manage Roles" you cant use RLS without it

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Using RLS in this way is currently not supported.